# convert 0.125 to 7-bit floating point format

Tags: c, floating-point

```
   Suppose we have a 7-bit computer that uses IEEE floating-point arithmetic where a 
floating point number has 1 sign bit, 3 exponent bits, and 3 fraction bits. All of the bits in 
the hardware work properly. 

Recall that denormalized numbers will have an exponent of 000, and the bias for a 3-bit 
exponent is 3.
```

Number to convert is `-0.125`

This is my attempt

Convert to binary form

```
0.001
```

Move decimal

```
0001.0
```

So E = -3 since we moved decimal right 3 times

```
E = e -bias 
-3 = e -3
```

So
e = 0
and M = 0?
That gives me

```
1 000 000
```

which is wrong. The correct answer should be `1 000 100`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Convert *from* decimal form. Move *radix point.*

Comment: Is this not what I am going?

Comment: Just terminology. There is such a thing as decimal FP, so if you use decimal terminology to refer to binary numbers it's confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The bias is 3, so the exponent of `1.0` is stored as 3. Therefore to get 1/8 you would want to store zero, but that is the representation of a denormal number. Denormal numbers must store the leading bit explicitly so the mantissa becomes `100` not `000`. Needing to store that `1` causes the precision to drop, which is symptomatic of denormalization.